# Accepted status in /connect/files REST service in lwc controller context

Tags: apex, rest-api, httprequest, files-connect

I am trying to convert docx to pdf with **/connect/files** service.
Sample code:

```
String ContentDocumentId = '0697Q000002LuE1QAK'; //some .docx id
HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('callout:ApexMDAPI/services/data/v55.0/connect/files/'+ContentDocumentId+'/rendition?type=PDF');
HttpResponse response=new Http().send(req);
Blob b = response.getBodyAsBlob();
```

It's work great in dev console, but in apex LWC controller I have 202 status code, and error in body:

> [{"errorCode":"FILE_PROCESSING_INCOMPLETE","message":"Creating
> renditions of the file."}]

Is there any way to make it work?

user: system admin;
authorization: connected app -> auth. provider -> named credentials (full access everywhere);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error, it's saying that the processing hasn't completed yet. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_files_rendition.htm) states:

> For shared files, renditions process asynchronously after upload. For private files, renditions process when the first file preview is requested, and aren’t available immediately after the file is uploaded.

In other words, it should be sufficient to just request another preview later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Problem was, that in dev console or postman I used "old" file Id, which was already handled.